# Why does AAssetDir_getNextFileName always return null?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to load some shader files for an Android App written in C++. It's using the `NativeActivity` and `native_app_glue`. I'm having a hard time actually getting the Android Asset system to work as expected.

The simplest case that I've tried is:

```
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>

void android_main(struct android_app *app) {
  AAssetDir *dir = AAssetManager_openDir(app->activity->assetManager, "");
  if (dir != nullptr) {
    LOGD("Opened Dir");

    LOGD("Filename: %s", AAssetDir_getNextFileName(dir));

    AAssetDir_close(dir);
  } else {
    LOGE("Failed to open dir");
  }
}
```

`AAssetManager_openDir` returns a valid `AAssetDir` ptr but `AAssetDir_getNextFileName` always returns nullptr. The NDK's `asset_manager.h` header seems to imply that my call should be absolutely valid.

```
/**
 * Open the named directory within the asset hierarchy.  The directory can then
 * be inspected with the AAssetDir functions.  To open the top-level directory,
 * pass in "" as the dirName.
 *
 * The object returned here should be freed by calling AAssetDir_close().
 */
```

I also seem to be unable to refer to any files by a known file path with other `AAssetManager` calls.

```
AAssetManager_open(app->activity->assetManager, "shaders/triangle.vert.spv", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
```

Also fails even though in my APK I can clearly see the files living correctly in `assets/shaders`. I can't find any relevant errors from my app in the **Logcat**. I couldn't find anything relevant in the Android permissions documents about needing some sort of permission to read internal assets.

I'm currently building against Android 28 with the latest **NDK r19**. Here is my current android-sdk package set that  I'm working with:

```
Installed packages:
  Path                 | Version      | Description                    | Location
  -------              | -------      | -------                        | -------
  build-tools;27.0.3   | 27.0.3       | Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 | build-tools\27.0.3\
  emulator             | 28.0.25      | Android Emulator               | emulator\
  ndk-bundle           | 19.2.5345600 | NDK                            | ndk-bundle\
  patcher;v4           | 1            | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools       | 28.0.2       | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-21 | 2            | Android SDK Platform 21        | platforms\android-21\
  platforms;android-28 | 6            | Android SDK Platform 28        | platforms\android-28\
  tools                | 26.0.1       | Android SDK Tools 26.0.1       | tools\
```

I currently test by deploying to a Pixel 2 XL with the latest patches.

Am I putting assets in the wrong folder? Is there some recent permission changes I've missed?

---

**EDIT #1:**

Did some more investigation. Placed a `test.txt` at the root of my APK's assets directory so the APK now has `assets/test.txt`. I've tried just opening a handle to this file with:

```
AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(app->activity->assetManager, "test.txt",
                                   AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
if (asset != nullptr) {
  LOGD("Opened test file");
  AAsset_close(asset);
} else {
  LOGE("Failed to open test file");
}
```

The app prints "Failed to open test file" to the Logcat. Still at a loss for what may be causing this.

---

**EDIT #2:** Replying to the first answer.

Trying a more complete code example as suggested doesn't yield any new results:

```
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
void android_main(struct android_app *app) {
  AAssetManager *assetManager = app->activity->assetManager;
  if (assetManager != nullptr) {
    AAssetDir *assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(assetManager, "");
    if (assetDir != nullptr) {
      uint32_t fileOpenedCounter = 0;
      const char *filename = (const char *)NULL;
      while ((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir)) != NULL) {
        AAsset *asset =
            AAssetManager_open(assetManager, filename, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
        if (asset != nullptr) {
          LOGD("Opened test file");
          fileOpenedCounter++;
          char buf[1024];
          int nb_read = 0;
          while ((nb_read = AAsset_read(asset, buf, 27)) > 0) {
            LOGD("buf: %s", buf);
          }

          AAsset_close(asset);
        } else {
          LOGE("Failed to open test file");
        }
      }
      LOGD("Opened %d files from root directory", fileOpenedCounter);
      AAssetDir_close(assetDir);
    } else {
      LOGE("Failed to open root directory");
    }
  } else {
    LOGE("Asset Manager was invalid");
  }
}
```

All I get from the Logcat is the debug log: "Opened 0 files from root directory". This seems to imply that the AAssetManager pointer I have is valid and it can *open* the directory but it can't find any files or subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out. It's a really dumb issue that I doubt most will run into but I'm going to document it here.

Some backstory that I did not think was relevant. I'm not using Android Studio. I'm using the [fips](https://github.com/floooh/fips) build system. It has a [simple python script](https://github.com/floooh/fips/blob/master/tools/android-create-apk.py) that packages the APK. The script is called from CMake.

I did not understand how aapt packaged asset files. So what I was doing was running a post-build script that would run `aapt add` and add my shader files into the APK and then re-align and re-zip the APK.

Taking another look at the aapt tool's help command output I realized there was the `-A` flag for adding an assets directory during APK compilation. **I was improperly adding my assets into the APK in the first place**

The fix was dead simple:

- Re-route shader compilation to build into an `assets` directory next to where fips runs its APK packaging.
- Add `'-A', 'assets'` to the AAPT packaging command in the fips packaging script

A quick look at the change:

```
# package the APK
cmd = [
    AAPT,
    'package',
    '-v', '-f',
    '-S', 'res',
    '-M', 'AndroidManifest.xml',
    '-A', 'assets',
    '-I', SDK_HOME + 'platforms/android-' + args.version + '/android.jar',
    '-F', args.path + args.name + '-unaligned.apk',
    'bin'
]
```

So yeah. This had nothing to do with the Android NDK APIs and far more with the actual APK packaging step. Too bad there's nothing in the NDK API to report that a file wasn't found, which would have been a tip-off. There was also no warning from the aapt tool that using `aapt add` didn't really add assets to the assets directory in the way I thought it did.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
AAssetManager *assetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManagerFromJava);
if(assetManager != nullptr) {
    AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(assetManager, "");
    const char* filename = (const char*)NULL;
    while ((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir)) != NULL) {
        AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, filename, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
        if (asset != nullptr) {
            ALOGI("Opened test file");
            char buf[1024];
            int nb_read = 0;
            while ((nb_read = AAsset_read(asset, buf, 27)) > 0) {
                ALOGI("buf: %s", buf);
            }

            AAsset_close(asset);
        } else {
            ALOGI("Failed to open test file");
        }
    }
    AAssetDir_close(assetDir);
}
```

`asset` pointer is fine and the file contents are printed from **Logcat** as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

---

**Edit #1:**

For your specific case, try to replace

```
AAssetManager *assetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManagerFromJava);
```

with your own Native pointer (please ensure `app->activity->assetManager` is a proper valid pointer)

```
AAssetManager *assetManager = app->activity->assetManager
```

Comment: The `AAssetManager *assetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManagerFromJava);` line isn't going to work for me. I'm using the NativeActivity so I don't have any Java code. I'm using the android_app* object passed in to me by the native_app_glue. The NativeActivity created by that glue layer has an AAssetManager pointer which is valid and should work according to the docs I've been reading. Unless there's something different in your snippet that I've missed?

Comment: I tried a more complete example based off of the code you provided and added it to the main question as Edit #2.